# Designing a "task" layer between client and network that organizes the synchronous network/api calls

Tags: android, design-patterns, software-design

For the app i'm working on, we have bunch of api calls that accomplish certain things. Usually each thing takes more than one api call. What i want to design is a middle layer where the UI/Client can just say do a certain task, middle layer would invoke that task, and task would handle all the api call sequence..

I'm having a hard time picking the right design patterns. Basically i was thinking a mediator type pattern that mediates interactions between UI, network and tasks. And everything would only talk to mediator, but then this might make the mediator too complicated. Also one more requirement is that the tasks can be composed of other tasks (one task might depend on another task and call it and wait for it to finish)..

Is there a general design pattern related to something like this that already exists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Virgil Dobjanschis Google IO REST explains a great pattern for decoupling network operations (REST in his case) from the UI, you can watch the video here http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xHXn3Kg2IQE it should be a great inspiration to get you started.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest one i can think off, and i'm afraid i'm not a design pattern guru or anything, is the command pattern, certainly a starting point for something a bit more complicated. 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern

Comment: thanks, yeah that's what i kinda started building on but it's too simple in the sense that i think i need to combine a few other ones for communication. Observer pattern doesn't work because they are in different threads and so on.